# Loop inside the Loop Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a problem making a loop iside the main loop in Wordpress. Basicly I want to get `the_excerpt()` for all post on page. The code looks like this but it still generate the excerpt only for the first post.

```html
 <?php $i= 0; ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="content-post-wrapper">
                    <p class="postmetadata"><?php the_category( ', ' ); ?></p>
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <small><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> <?php echo meks_time_ago(); ?></small>
                    <?php if ( in_category( '16') ) : ?>
                            <div class="entry-promo">
                                <div class="img-wrapper-large">
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large'); ?> 
                                </div>
                                <?php echo awesome_excerpt(wp_trim_excerpt(),1); ?>
                            </div>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <div class="entry">
                            <div class="img-wrapper-medium">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail'); ?>
                                <?php comments_number(); ?>
                            </div>
                            
                            <?php if ( $i<99 ) : ?>  
                                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php $i=$i+1; ?>
                            
                            <!--<?php echo awesome_excerpt(wp_trim_excerpt(),1); ?>-->
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
        <?php endwhile; else : ?>
            <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Also i tried with `<?php if ( !$post->post_excerpt ) :?>
                                <!-- Display explicit excerpt-->
                                  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>` but the result is the same. :(

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do if you haven't already is to switch [WordPress debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) on. Check if this is providing you with any errors.

Another thing to try; ignore the rest of the logic for now, and add the excerpt code straight after the loop begins. This will help simplify things and see what (if anything) is being returned. See below:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    the_excerpt();
endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Let me know how you get on.